# Entity Framework Core: Adding an object with a List to a DbContext results in an empty List

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We are attempting to save an Entity Framework Model to the database.

In the model a Track always contains a Message and a Message MAY have any number of Messages in its List of Retransmits.

When saving the model, we check if the Track model already exists in the database; If not, we simply add the Track to the DbContext.

```
public class Track
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TrackId { get; set; }
    public virtual Message Message { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
    public Guid TrackId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Message> Retransmits { get; set; }
}

public void Save (Track track)
{
    using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        Track foundTrack = Read(track.TrackId); // Returns a Track if it already exists in the database

        if (foundTrack == null)
        {
            context.Add(track);
        }
        else
        {
            // Update the Track. Not relevant to this question
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

// Returns a Track if it exists in the database or null
public Track Read(Guid trackId)
{
    using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        return context.Tracks
            .Include(t => t.Message)
                .ThenInclude(m => m.Retransmits)
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.TrackId == trackId);
    }
}
```

When adding Track to the DbContext Entity Framework will always clear the List of Retransmits. This means that a Message can contain one Message in its List of Retransmits before calling DbContext.Add, but after calling DbContext.Add it will suddenly have 0. Entity Framework is effectively clearing the list and not adding it to the database.

We expected that the List of Retransmits would be added to the DbContext and NOT deleted from the model without warning.

During debugging we discovered that changing the List of Retransmits from `List<Message>` to `List<AnyOtherObject>` returned the expected results and rows in the database.

It seems that because the List of Retransmits is of the same type as the class it is contained within (I.e. A Message can contain many Messages), Entity Framework treats it differently.

We have also tried to configure a One-to-Many relationship between the entities where `modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().HasMany(m => m.Retransmits)` makes no difference. And even
`modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().HasMany(m => m.Retransmits).WithOne(m => m.Parent)`
where Parent is a reference back to the containing object of a retransmitted Message. However, this resulted in a StackOverflow exception.

What could be the reason for Entity Framework refusing to add the list to the database? Is there any way to configure Entity Framework to allow a Message to contain a List of Retransmits(being of type Message) and have it added to the database as expected? Or are we doing something wrong entirely?

[I have attached an image of the behavior in Visual Studio's Debugger.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHv0q.png)

EDIT: We have tried the latest stable Entity Framework Core version 2.2.6, as well as Entity Framework Core version 3.0.0 - Preview 9. The same behavior exists across both versions.

EDIT EDIT: The following code initializes the model and should reproduce the issue.

```
public void ReproduceIssue ()
{
    // Create a Track and Message
    Track track = new Track()
    {
        Message = new Message()
    };

    track.Message.TrackId = track.TrackId;

    // Create a Retransmitted Message
    Message retransmit = new Message()
    {
        TrackId = track.TrackId
    };

    // Add the Retransmitted Message to the List
    track.Message.Retransmits.Add(retransmit);

    Save(track);
}
```

Comment: Let clarify the usage scenario. `track.Message` is new because `MessageId` is `default(Guid))` and is supposed to be created before the track, correct? How about `Message` objects inside `track.Message.Retransmits`? Can you expand them in the image before calling `Add(track)`? Or better, provide small code snippet which creates `Track` object and calls the `Save` method which reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Ivan Track.Message is created at the same time as Track is. One cannot exist without the other but retransmits may not exist at all. I have edited the original question with the setup to reproduce the issue. Also here is an image of the expanded object in Visual Studio: [link](https://imgur.com/a/Opb9yvd)

Comment: From a plain logic/database design point, why does a retransmit contain the whole message again. Assuming that a retransmit is simply trying to transmit the same message again, shouldn't there be a message table and a transmits table and a message can have zero to n transmits, without duplicating all the message data over and over?

Comment: Something is wrong with this model. Is there any fluent configuration? W/o relationship configuration EF Core assumes one-to-one relationship from `Track` to `Message`, which kind of explains the behavior because you are assigning the same `TrackId` to many messages, which requires one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Thank you for all your input. We are making changes, going back and forth on some design ideas. We have a working prototype which seems to work fine with Entity Framework. I will post an answer when we have some results :)

Answer (score 0):

We made some changes to our model. While I believe Entity Framework should never throw any information away without issuing a warning / exception, we did circumvented the issue.

I would like to post the code, but it is a bit more complex as the original question left out a lot of code details. However, the solution was basically to configure a many-to-many relationship between Messages using a join table.

After that, it behaved as expected.